# SQL query a column based on two other columns in different tables (screenshot inside)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to resolve this pb:

[click to see the sketch of the tables for explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t44n2.png)

Basically I want to join the `Name` column from the `Description` table on the `Unique_Number` of the `ID` table. The issue is that there is not primary key in the `Description` table and unique values are only found when combining the two columns.

Thanks!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Is this a homework question that you have scanned in and posted here?

Comment: Please post the DDL and DML statements for your tables, the expected result of the query **and** your attempt at answering the question all in a text format. Please do not post links to images as the links can break and images are not easy to extract information from.

Comment: It is not a homework question.. It is for work, I already have mapped many tables and this is the last one, I am stuck because for this one there is no primary key and the uniqueness of a row will come from the combination of two values from other fields.

Edit: I will remember not to post images

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in joining these two tables as you can't retrieve any useful information after joining.

Also, going by your column names how can `names` be joined on `unique_id`.

If you want to join these two tables to get the `unique_id` and `names` for same codes you should do inner join on `codes` columns.

```
SELECT CONCAT(unique_number,name)
FROM table_id a,table_description b
WHERE a.code_a = b.code_a
AND a.code_b =  b.code_b;
```

Comment: This is  a simplification and the data contained in the column Name of the table description is crucial. I would like to join this column on the table ID (for each Unique_Number I would have the "Name" information). Does this help at all?

Comment: Thats what I m saying. How can you join a varchar with a number. I mean 'tweedi' = 5. How is it possible.

Comment: Or do a cartesian product of two tables (join without any condition). After that alter the table and set the primary key as combination of both unique_id and name.

Comment: You are right, In fact in both tables there are 2 fields which contains the same type of values. If the combinations of the 2 values in the columns of the table ID matches the combination of the 2 values in the columns of the table DESCRIPTION then I would like to stick the column "Name" of the table DESCRIPTION at the end of the table ID

Comment: Yes you can do this way.

Comment: OK that's good, can you provide any indication on what method I should use to achieve this? I am new to sql and keen to make some research but so far I don't where to start for this one

Comment: See my updated answer. Hope you are looking for this only.

Comment: Excellent will try to play around this tommorow at work and will let you know how it went. Thanks a lot for your help.